# How to dispatch an event manually in Paper.JS?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

What I am trying to achieve is to clone an item on the canvas when I click on it and drag the clone without releasing the mouse.

```
             menuItem.onMouseDown = function(event){
                var clone = this.clone();
                clone.onMouseDrag = function(event){
                    this.position+=event.delta;
                    console.log(event);
                }
                var ev = new MouseEvent('mousedrag',
                            event.event);
                ev.event.type="mousemove";
                ev.delta={x:0,y:0};
                ev.target=clone;
                ev.point=event.point;
                clone.emit('mousedrag',ev);
            };
```

I tried this, I believe I need something like this. So when I click the `menuItem` I clone it, and set up the event for the clone, and then `emit` an event on it. But the emitted event needs to be set up, and that is where my idea falls apart. Any thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do things a bit differently; I wouldn't try to swap the handlers in the middle of the selection/dragging but would just logically swap the items temporarily:

```
menuItem = new Path.Circle(view.bounds.center, 25);
menuItem.fillColor = 'red';

var oldMenuItem = null;

menuItem.onMouseDown = function(e) {
    oldMenuItem = this.clone();
    oldMenuItem.fillColor = 'green';
}

menuItem.onMouseDrag = function(e) {
    this.position += e.delta;
}

menuItem.onMouseUp = function(e) {
    // swap menuItem and oldMenuItem to keep mouse handling on the
    // original item?
    var t = this.position;
    this.position = oldMenuItem.position;
    oldMenuItem.position = t;
}
```

Here's a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/dZFBawIxEIX/ypCLK5UIhV6UpQd76UEQpKduD9lkdIPZmSWbdSnif29i0bqyzS15M+99MzkJUjWKhdgeMOhKzIRmk+4F1Ujde8AaciDsYaNCJVfWa4fZ0WIvS+7ItFIjBfQzeH6ZLv+a5M46t2LHPrZPPJpJFAs6Kg/szPrOunPuIt06mdbctfjGPUV915EOlinDKZwKgniGBqGyEcIxYZYAHgqGHHuPSInkPJro1X488ZLRcGvTOzzlgNKgC+o/p49m3Gc+h1p9lwhtrxq4LViRuWd+/S1OuwrXAa/hyzGgfDDxQ+mYlFwTe/zu0qM6NGwptGLx+XX+AQ==) that implements something similar (I think) to what you're looking for. Just pretend the red circle is the menu item.

It is possible to construct a ToolEvent or MouseEvent (depending on the handler) but that is currently undocumented and would require a trip to the source code on github. Edit: I got curious and took a trip to github.

The `MouseEvent` constructor code is in the events directory but the constructor is used and the `.emit` function is called from the [CanvasView.js](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/view/CanvasView.js) module (search for `new MouseEvent`). But in order to simulate what you want to you'll need to simulate the entire chain of events in order to keep the internal state consistent. So you'd need to 1) emit a mouseup event on the original item, 2) emit a mousedown on the new item, and 3) emit mousemoves on the new item, and 3) detach the handler from the original item and attach a handler to the new item in between 1 & 2. (You might not need to emit the original mouseup if you detach the handler before.) If you've created a `Tool` you will need to create a `ToolEvent` rather than a `MouseEvent`.

Anyway, I can see why it's not documented - there is a lot to keep in mind. I wanted to update this answer to reflect your original question even though the answer is still that it is probably best to find another way to perform this action.

In case someone really wants or needs to do this:

1. Mouse events are constructed via the code in [MouseEvent.js](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/event/MouseEvent.js)
2. The constructor is used, and the event emitted, in [CanvasView.js](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/view/CanvasView.js)
3. Event processing is driven in [View.js](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/view/View.js)
4. Tool events are constructed via code in [ToolEvent.js](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/tool/ToolEvent.js)

OTOH, emitting a frame event is easy:

```
view.emit('frame', {});
```

Comment: this seems to solve my problem, but thanks for the clue I will take a look at the ToolEvent on github

Comment: So what you're doing is not dragging the clone, but dragging the original and putting a clone in its place?

Comment: Yes, and then swapping them back on mouse up. If I were coding from scratch I would use `view.on('mousedown', ...)`, and mousedrag, mouseup to avoid situations where one overlaps the other, etc. I wouldn't need to switch handlers then because the event is view-wide. But I would need to do my own test on mouse down - not a big deal unless there are a large number of menuItems.

Comment: Thanks for the edition it i really useful, however your original solution is just perfect for me.